# AngularJS, how to show a scrollbar when a list grows

Tags: html, css, angularjs, scrollbar, angular-material

I would like create a screen (AnguarJS, angular-material) :

```
<div layout="column">
   <div> <!-- 80% of window browser -->
      <md-list>
         <md-list-item ng-repeat="person in people">

         </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
   </div>
   <div> <!-- 20% of window browser -->

   </div>
</div>
```

When the list (md-list) is too long I would like a vertical scrollbar appear.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do using Angular Material layout

```
<body>
  <div flex="100" layout="column">

    <md-toolbar>
      With toolbar for example, but you can use a div
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-content>
      A scrollbar appear when the content is overflow
    </md-content>

    <div>
      Your footer is already visible when the content above is overflow 
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add styles like below:

```
md-list {
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: angular material has `flex` directive for this

Comment: it would but using hard code values wouldn't be as responsive if OP wants to maintain the 80/20 relationship shown in question. Just mentioning a more responsive flexbox option is all in my comment

Comment: you're right, anyway, I'm not sure how would it work - just the same like flex in css?

Comment: yes... the directive attributes are used for flex css. See angular material docs

Comment: I tried to use the angular-material flex property but I didn't manage to limit 80/20 of the vertical brower page size.

Comment: I tried to use the angular-material flex property but I didn't manage to limit 80/20 of the vertical brower page size. I tried too md-content element. All example I found about this use style height:600px hard coded (% doesn't work). This isn't a good practice. But there is an onther way using an own directive.